# Performance difference between spring javaconfig, xml config and annotations

Tags: java, spring

Our Spring configuration contains about 1200 beans, and we use component-scan/@Autowired. If we exported the ApplicationContext as an Xml (and still used @Autowired), we saved about 10% on context startup-time.

What can we expect if we try spring javaconfig ?

Comment: Only because I am interested in: How long does the startup take for 1200 bean?

Comment: On my machine 10 seconds, that's a mocked version (without all the heavy stuff)

Comment: I've removed the javaconfig tag:  That was an experimental extension to Spring 2.5, now redundant in Spring 3.

Comment: @Raplh; it turns out I was wrong. We were using a version of spring-beans with a dirty patch applied to make things faster. 25 seconds without this version. Unfortunately the patch is not entirely correct according to all the myriads of use cases spring supports.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is likely not between annotations and XML, but instead it'll be the startup performance hit of using component-scanning, which *is* slow.  If you add component-scanning to your XML version, you should find that it's just as slow.

Comment: The 10% difference is basically what we get because we disable component scan when using xml (If I ignore the actual load time for xml, which I would assume would be something like 100-200ms).

Comment: There is a cost associated with extensive autowire by type too, but we did not remove that because we used xml + autowire (just exported simple "bean" declarations from the running context using a small loop)

Comment: @krosenvold: My current favourite approach (which will likely change again next week) is to use `@Bean` along with constructor injection in the bean classes themselves. No autowiring. It makes my dependencies so much easier to follow, and constructors are more usable than they are with XML.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess a bit less, because no parsing will have ho happen (the annotations are 'parsed' with reflection, the xml - with an xml parser).

That, however, should not be a reason to choose one configuration option over the other. Startup time is not important for performance.

Comment: Startup time is important for me as a developer, so to me it's the most important performance aspect of them all ;)

Comment: @krosenvold if you redeploy on each change.. yes, but you should not do that

Comment: The tradeoff between redeploying vs using something jrebel like is not always as clear cut as you'd like, especially if your container startup already is quite fast. And there's stuff like integration tests.

Comment: @krosenvold I didn't mean JRebel. Hotswap is working for all non-structural code changes. As for integration tests - I agree, but they are usually automated and whether it takes 7 or 9 minutes to run them wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I actually tried this a while back and depressingly it was not faster.. or at least not perceivable faster. In some cases when I actually measured it was slower (ever so slightly). I wish I had numbers but it was one of those quick tests for my own benefit. I also didn't have 1200 beans but about 200.

I also noticed mixing XML and Java config gave the worst performance (ever so slightly).

What I have found to be the bottleneck in my Spring bootup time is Hibernate. I'm doing another project with much of the same config w/o Hibernate using JDBC and the bootup time is about 1/3.