# Advantages of using spring stereotypes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am developing a web application using spring-mvc.

Now the @Controller, @Service and @Repository stereotypes are available.

I found @Controller particulary useful, specially because I am using

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.cool.controller"/>
```

Now, regarding @Service and @Repository, so far looks like

1. The exceptions are better handled if the class is annotated with the correct stereotype, ok, that is an advantage I acknowlegde
2. I could use component-scan for services and DAOs/repositories, however I do not like the idea of using component-scan, since it slows the startup time of the application, and that is a key feature for me (even if it is only 1 sec and I redeploy once per week)

So, apart from the better exceptions, any other advantage at all? Does annotating classes have an impact on performance?

Comment: Look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645864/performance-difference-between-spring-javaconfig-xml-config-and-annotations

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Explanation of stereotypes :**

- `@Service` - Annotate all your service classes with @Service. This layer knows the unit of work. All your business logic will be in Service classes. Generally methods of service layer are covered under transaction. You can make multiple DAO calls from service method, if one transaction fails all transactions should rollback.
- `@Repository` - Annotate all your DAO classes with @Repository. All your database access logic should be in DAO classes.
- `@Component` - Annotate your other components (for example REST resource classes) with component stereotype.
- `@Autowired` - Let Spring auto-wire other beans into your classes using @Autowired annotation.

`@Component` is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component. `@Repository`, `@Service`, and `@Controller` are specializations of `@Component` for more specific use cases, for example, in the persistence, service, and presentation layers, respectively.

**Reasons to use them :**

- The main advantage of using @Repository or @Service over @Component is that it's easy to write an AOP pointcut that targets, for instance, all classes annotated with @Repository.
- You don't have to write `bean` definitions in context xml file. Instead annotate classes and use those by autowiring.
- Specialized annotations help to clearly demarcate application layers (in a standard 3 tiers application).

Now, Practically performance impact of using context xml beans & annotations is the same. Component scanning is a bit more expensive (when you scan for @Service, @Component). The annotations are 'parsed' with reflection, the xml - with an xml parser. But, as you said, it is startup-time - it happens only once. And on a moderate machine it starts pretty quickly even with annotations.

Comment: I am not a big fan of autowiring, I honestly prefer to manually specify which bean is injected (using xml), with tools like intellij, it is not a big deal to read the code. Apart from that, the AOP seems interesting, could you edit your answer and provide me an quick example (no need for code really, just a use case)

Comment: Please go through articles explained in following sites : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html and http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/

Answer (score 2):

Component scan saves you from defining each bean manually via xml or java configuration.

Multiple stereo types are there to define layers like service layer, data layer, etc. Also based on different stereo types if you want to do something specific then you can do so.

Comment: I know what component scan does, and I also know that it comes with a cost, it is not a problem to use xml for me. Regarding stereotypes and layers, good point, but what "Also based on different stereo types if you want to do something specific then you can do so." means? Any example?

Comment: I meant you can define more stereo types to create more layers if you need to.

Comment: Fair enough, how does that represent an advantage over say packages or naming conventions (being the devil advocate here, don't get me wrong :)