# Why @Component is used in Controller annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations

Below is source code of For Component Interface

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Component {
```

and for Spring Controller annotation is as below

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Controller {
```

Why @Component is added in Controller annotation ? What is its purpose ? What if I remove this line ?

I am clear about below annotation types which are used to create custom annotations.

```
@Documented Whether to put the annotation in Javadocs
@Retention  When the annotation is needed
@Target     Places the annotation can go    
@Inherited  Whether subclasses get the annotation
```

Comment: `@Controller` is a `@Component`. The `@Component` is used as a meta-annotation here so that it can be picked-up using component-scanning. The `@Controller` is a special component which will have some added functionality. If you remove the `@Component` annotation component-scan will not detect it anymore. You can also create your own `@Component` based annotations.

Comment: @M.Deinum: you should poast that as an answer.

Comment: ok in this case @Component was need for component-scanning. Similarly if we take some other example of custom annotation. which has some parameters also , how will that behave(while using with meta-annotations like @Component)? One option is we can write our annotation processor to read that. My doubt is that "is there any other behavior also comes up with this ?" if not then without writing annotation processor it should be meaningless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Controller` is a `@Component` (just like `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Endpoint` etc.).

The @Component is used as a meta-annotation here so that it can be picked-up using component-scanning. Next to that the @Controller is a special component which will have some added functionality (Spring MVC takes care of that). If you remove the @Component annotation component-scan will not be able to detect it anymore.

You can also create your own `@Component` based annotations by simply creating your own annotation and putting `@Component` on it.

Comment: ok in this case @Component was need for component-scanning. Similarly if we take some other example of custom annotation. which has some parameters also , how will that behave(while using with meta-annotations like @Component)? One option is we can write our annotation processor to read that. My doubt is that "is there any other behavior also comes up with this ?" if not then without writing annotation processor it should be meaningless.

Comment: An annotation alone doesn't do a thing, there needs to be something that processes it. An annotation is nothing more then meta-data...

Answer (score 1):

`@Component` is a generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component. `@Repository`, `@Service`, and `@Controller` are specializations of `@Component` for more specific use cases, for example, in the persistence, service, and presentation layers, respectively.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051656/advantages-of-using-spring-stereotypes/16105106#16105106)