# Bad use of java annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I know java annotation is a powerfull tool. For me, [project lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) is a great example of extreme use. But i've heard that sometimes, it is better not to use annotations.

Can you give me examples of bad annotations, so i have an idea of what to avoid ?

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108959/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-annotations-non-compiler-compared-to-xml-config-files

Comment: Where did you heard that? In what context? ...without being more specific, it seems difficult to answer properly.

Comment: a little more context would help here. Annotations are helpful to use at some places e.g. in JUnit classes to avoid method naming conventions. But sometimes, like in Spring controllers, I find DI through xml config to be a better choice as against annotations as it takes out the config part outside your class. I would say it depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like asking in which situations a spoon isn't useful.

Instead it can typically beneficial to use annotations when

- You're constructing a framework which will be used by many components.

  - For instance I once made a gui framework and added annotations such as @CSS etc.
  - Hibernate provides in my opinion a great approach to annotation based database mapping
- You need to perform some compile-time task, like generating javadoc.
- Dependency injection